# Can't run Karma tests in AngularJS project

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, intellij-idea, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I created AngularJS project in IntellijIdea. I setup run configs using Karma with **karma.conf.js**

```
    //jshint strict: false
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    basePath: './app',

    files: [
      'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      'bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
      'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'components/**/*.js',
      'view*/**/*.js'
    ],

    autoWatch: true,

    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    browsers: ['Chrome'],

    plugins: [
      'karma-chrome-launcher',
      'karma-firefox-launcher',
      'karma-jasmine',
      'karma-junit-reporter'
    ],

    junitReporter: {
      outputFile: 'test_out/unit.xml',
      suite: 'unit'
    }

  });
};
```

When I'm running it, it opens browser and shows that Karma connected but it fails in console with error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
>   at http://localhost:9876/base/components/version/interpolate-filter.js?1f60feb7532929c924d39ca3c4132660d6eaca96:3
>   Here is my **interpolate-filter.js**

```
    'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.version.interpolate-filter', [])
.filter('interpolate', ['version', function(version) {
  return function(text) {
    return String(text).replace(/\%VERSION\%/mg, version);
  };
}]);
```

Here is my screenshot of project and console error
[image]

Comment: AngularJS tests run fine for me using same karma config. Just to make things clear: do you have angular.js available in `<project root>/app/bower_components/angular/` folder? as far as I can see from your screenshots, neither karma nor Idea can resolve Angular

Comment: also, please can you provide the output from 'Karma server' tab?

Comment: Since there is `basePath: './app',` files will be referred from the base path

Comment: @lena thanx. it helped